# How to update dot product in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I don't know how to update a dot product.
More specifically, I have a class in which I define in `totv = np.dot(x, values)` in the `__init__` function, where `x` and `values` are two NumPy arrays.
Then in one the following methods I change one value in the array `x`.
How can I automatically update the dot product `totv`, in later methods?

Comment: why don't you also modify totv as ``self.totv = np.dot(x, values)``.

Comment: `totv` is just an array, the numerical result of the `dot`.  It has no record of the arrays used in the calculation.  If you hope to avoid another full `dot`, you'll need to show us, with an example and/or some algebra, how your value change will change `totv`.  In other words, convince us that a short-cut is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually want a property definition of totv?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> class Tot: 
...     def __init__(self,x,values):
...             self.x = x
...             self.values = values
...     @property
...     def totv(self):
...             return np.dot(self.x,self.values)
... 
>>> tot = Tot(np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,0,1]))
>>> tot.totv
4
>>> tot.x = np.array([14,14,19])
>>> tot.totv
33
>>>
```

Here `tot.totv` is calculated each time it is referenced

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you have a situation like the following:

```
import numpy as np
class my_class():
    def __init__(self, x, values):
        self.x = x
        self.values = values
        self.totv = np.dot(x, values)
    def update_x(self, i, v):
        self.x[i] = v

inst = my_class(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]))
inst.update_x(1, 4)
print(inst.__dict__)
```

which gives:

```
{'x': array([1, 4, 3]), 'values': array([4, 5, 6]), 'totv': 32}
```

because:

```
>>> 1 * 4 + 2 * 5 + 3 * 6
32
```

---

So you would like that when you modify the `x` attribute in the `update_x` method, `self.totv` is re-evaluated.

I'm afraid that their is no alternative to calling: `self.totv = ...` every time you modify `self.x`. However, you can improve the readability of your code by defining a method which updates the `totv` attribute:

```
class my_class():
    def update_totv(self):
        self.totv = np.dot(self.x, self.values)
    def __init__(self, x, values):
        self.x = x
        self.values = values
        self.totv = np.dot(x, values)
    def update_x(self, i, v):
        self.x[i] = v
        self.update_totv()
```

Now, so long as you call `self.update_totv()` after each modification of `self.x`, `self.totv` will be updated accordingly. Hence, the first code using this new class declaration gives the correct output:

```
{'x': array([1, 4, 3]), 'values': array([4, 5, 6]), 'totv': 42}
```

since:

```
>>> 1 * 4 + 4 * 5 + 3 * 6
42
```